# Add methods to a Rails engine model from a Rails plugin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rubygems, ruby-on-rails-5, ruby-on-rails-plugins

I'm writing a Rails plugin to extend a Rails engine. Namely `MyPlugin` has `MyEngine` as a dependency.

On my Rails engine I have a `MyEngine::Foo` model.

I'd like to add new methods to this model so I created a file in my plugin `app/models/my_engine/foo.rb` which has the following code:

```
module MyEngine
  class Foo

        def sayhi
            puts "hi"
        end

  end
end
```

If I enter the Rails console on the plugin dummy application I can find `MyEngine::Foo`, but runnning `MyEngine::Foo.new.sayhi` returns

> NoMethodError: undefined method `sayhi'

Why `MyPlugin` cannot see the updates to `MyEngine::Foo` model? Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, found out. To make `MyPlugin` aware and able to modify `MyEngine` models the engine must be required on the plugin `engine.rb` like so:

```
require "MyEngine"

module MyPlugin
  class Engine < ::Rails::Engine
    isolate_namespace MyPlugin

    # You can also inherit the ApplicationController from MyEngine
    config.parent_controller = 'MyEngine::ApplicationController'
  end
end
```

In order to extend `MyEngine::Foo` model I then had to create a file `lib/my_engine/foo_extension.rb`:

```rb
require 'active_support/concern'

module FooExtension
    extend ActiveSupport::Concern

    def sayhi
        puts "Hi!"
    end

    class_methods do 
        def sayhello
            puts "Hello!"
        end
    end
end

::MyEngine::Foo(:include, FooExtension)
```

And require it in `config/initializers/my_engine_extensions.rb`

```rb
require 'my_engine/foo_extension'
```

Now from `MyPlugin` I can:

```sh
 MyEngine::Foo.new.sayhi
 => "Hi!"
 MyEngine::Foo.sayhello
 => "Hello!"
```

See **ActiveSupport Concern** [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) for more details.