# How to extend in my app an AR model of my engine so Mobility doesn't complain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, inheritance, activerecord, mobility

In my plugin I'm inheriting few models from the engine and adding **Mobility** settings.

```rb
# my enginge
module MyEngine
  class Foo < ApplicationRecord
    def self.say_hi
      return "hi"
    end
  end
end
```

```rb
# my plugin
require 'my-engine'
module MyEngine
  class Foo
    include Mobility
    translates :name, type: :string
  end
end
```

Now if I look for the model in Rails console:

```sh
MyEngine::Foo.say_hi
ArgumentError: KeyValue backend can only be used by ActiveRecord or Sequel models
```

If I comment out Mobility settings everything works:

```sh
MyEngine::Foo.say_hi
=> "hi"
```

How to extend in my app an AR model `MyEngine::Foo` so Mobility doesn't complain?

Comment: I was trying the method explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45252778/1498118) but I still get the error.

Comment: Hmm I'm not quite sure I understand the question. You can't `translate` an attribute on a class using the (default) `key_value` backend unless the class inherits from either `ActiveRecord::Base` or `Sequel::Model`, otherwise Mobility doesn't know how to setup methods correctly. If you want to do something more flexible, you could use the `Mobility::Attributes` module builder directly, which you can create without knowing the class it will be included in right away. If you can provide more details I can explain how to do this.

Comment: Can you not have `class Foo < ApplicationRecord` in your plugin? That should fix the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45252778/1498118) does help with extending an engine model from a plugin, but doesn't help with mobility.

To use modify `MyEngine::Foo` to use mobilty you need to create an initializer `config/initializers/mobility_models_extension.rb` (make sure the file name is alphabetically after `mobility.rb` file).

```rb
:: MyEngine::Foo(:include, Mobility)
:: MyEngine::Foo.send(:translates, :name, type: :string)
```

See `send` [documentation](https://apidock.com/ruby/Object/send) and [initializers documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/initialization.html#railties-lib-rails-application-rb)